# Dell XPS 15 9520 and Dell WD22TB4 has became unreliable. 22.10 and 23.04

Tags: dell, thunderbolt, 23.04

I have been using my Dell XPS 15 9520 and a Dell Dock since October, and inside Ubuntu 22.10 Since January.  In the past 2 weeks it has started acting strange.
First, on a reboot with the dock attached, the dock is detected and authorized, my monitors are detected but they do not get a signal.  Ubuntu is under the belief that they are connected as they can be viewed from display settings and the system acts like they are hooked up.  I have further noticed that if I simply wait and leave the system alone for a while, (15 or more minutes?) the screens will start working.  As a test today, I rebooted and went to lunch.  Came back and upon waking up the screen they initialized just fine and I'm able to work.  Sometimes in this condition, if I disconnect a monitor, and reconnect, it will come back with the displays, however this is not reliable.  Sometimes it cannot detect the monitor and put's the resolution at 640X480, and othertimes it doesn't come back with anything.

I have also noticed that if I disconnect the dock and reconnect it, then the thunderbolt authorization get's an error. I have thrown all manner of boltctl forget and boltctl enroll at this, and usually it will NOT authorize and will not come back.  Sometimes I'm able to enroll, and for a moment my monitors come on, then a second or two later they go black and boltctl reports the same authorization error.
The error that I get is basically a Kernel input/output error. I'm further able to replicate this situation using: `echo 1 > /sys/bus/thunderbolt/devices/0-1/authorized`
which will often come back and say the same thing, input/output error.

My laptop itself is running it's latest Bios, however I've tried downgrading to bios from earlier this year to see if that would correct the issue, and it has not.  I've also booted to a live Ubuntu 22.10 and I get a similar behavior from the thunderbolt and boltctl.

Comment: Further observation: This morning I disconnected the dock, ran boltctl and saw that the dock was listed however disconnected.  I did 'boltctl forget -a', then 'boltctl' again to verify that it was no longer listed.  I then shut down the laptop, disconnected the power of the dock waited a few seconds while holding it's power button, then plugged power back in, plugged the dock back in, and booted the laptop.  Upon booting, thunderbolt device was authenticated, but no output on monitors.  I waited 15 minutes for my screen to shut off, and upon resuming, external monitors are working!  Thoughts?